# Single quotes configuration with deno fmt

Tags: format, deno, deno-fmt

Every time I use `deno fmt`, it automatically converts my single quotes into double quotes.

To be more specific, when `fmt` is applied to a statement like this:

```
console.log(  'Deno'   );
```

The statement is changed to:

```
console.log("Deno");
```

The expected behavior is to continue using **single quotes** by default.

Is there any configuration of `fmt` options?

Answer (score 5):

You can now change the default behaviour of `deno fmt` by creating a `deno.json` file:

```json
{
  "fmt": {
    "options": {
      "singleQuote": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there's no way to change default settings. Adding a config flag it's something that's being worked on, you can follow this [issue](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/3827)

Comment: According to the devs in the linked issue, the feature will not be implemented. They recommend using `dprint` for that.